# How to remove a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string

I have an string like this:

```
string s1 = "abc,tom,--Abc, tyu,--ghh";
```

This string is dynamic, and I need to remove all substrings starting with `"--"`.
Output for the example string:

```
s1 = "abc,tom, tyu";
```

How can I remove these substrings?

Comment: You should state how the ends of the substrings are marked.  It appears to be with either a comma or end of string, but you should really say that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Look at [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)</strike>

I am sorry, I should have read the question correctly.
Regex comes to mind, for your case.

EDIT

**LINQ**

```
string s1 = "abc,tom,--Abc, tyu,--ghh";
var s2 = s1
  .Split(',')
  .Where(s => s.StartsWith("--") == false)
  .Aggregate((start, next) => start + "," + next);
Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

Comment: String.Replace would not remove the item it would just remove the `--`

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
Regex.Replace(s1, "--[^,]*,?", "");
```

This will search the string for blocks that start with `--`, have some characters that are not commans (spaces or letter), and the comma (optional - there's no comma in the end).